# Show Kubernetes pod name from docker container running a .Net Core API

Tags: .net, docker, kubernetes, .net-core

Having a .NET Core API running inside a docker container on a Kubernetes cluster: how to tell the API the name of the pod.

Is there anyway to forward or inject the information?

This could be usefull to pin issues down to pods by enriching logs or connections.

Comment: I am not sure I understand clearly, do you mean to pass pod name as env var which can be used by the scripts running inside the container?

Comment: See this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/

Comment: if passing the pod name as env var allows me to use it in the c# code of the api, then yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Downward` API provides the way to expose information to containers.

Description from the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/):

> This page shows how a Pod can use environment variables to expose
> information about itself to Containers running in the Pod. Environment
> variables can expose Pod fields and Container fields.

Refer [this example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables) to see how information is exposed as the environment variables on the containers.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-envars-fieldref
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv MY_NODE_NAME MY_POD_NAME MY_POD_NAMESPACE;
          printenv MY_POD_IP MY_POD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT;
          sleep 10;
        done;
      env:
        - name: MY_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: MY_POD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
  restartPolicy: Never
```

The script running inside the container can then access this information from the environment variable.

Comment: nice. From there on I just need to read the env vars as usual and either fake them outside of kubernetes (e.g. localhost) or set them