# Looking for C# code to get details of Node and Pod that it is currently running on

Tags: .net-core, c#-4.0, azure-aks

I am writing with a request here, and It would be great if someone can share your thoughts about it from your experience.
Scenario - Consider we have a node as part of an AKS cluster and there are about three pods running on that node. There is an app deployed on all three pods.
I am looking for C# code snippet that can give you details of the Pod Name or Pod ID, Node Name or Node Id that it is running on.
Basically the hierarchical details of all the elements that the code is running on in AKS cluster.
Thanks in advance.

I am expecting the C# code to log details like how many times there were requests made to a perticular Pod.
So it can return Pod Id/Name, Node Id/Name etc

Answer (score 0):

If you have Application Insights enabled in your application you can enhance the telemetry with this information using the [addon](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Kubernetes):

[image]

If not you can use the code as an inspiration :-)
Or you use environment variables that you access in your code, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66487685/show-kubernetes-pod-name-from-docker-container-running-a-net-core-api)

Comment: Thank you for your response Peter. This helps.